# 'this' is window in getMediaUserCallback instead of Object

Tags: javascript, audio-recording

I am trying this in Chrome on a Mac:

```
function SoundRecorder() {
}

SoundRecorder.prototype.recordSound = function() {
  navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia || navigator.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.msGetUserMedia;
  if (!navigator.getUserMedia) {
    alert('Media is not supported in your browser');
    return;
  }
  navigator.getUserMedia({
    audio: true
  }, this.success, this.failure);
};

SoundRecorder.prototype.success = function(e) {
  console.log(this == window);
};

SoundRecorder.prototype.failure = function() {
  return alert('You denied permission');
};
```

When I run 
`new SoundRecorder().recordSound()`
it prints out true. Shouldn't the value of this be an 'instance' of SoundRecoder. I am missing something or is this a Chrome Bug?

I tried it in Firefox and the value of this was "SoundRecorder.prototype.success"

Comment: That's kinda weird, is it true if you make it "==="?

Comment: It seems you are passing a direct reference to the function, so it is called without setting its *this*, therefore it defaults to the global object.

Comment: Why would it be different in FF tho?

Comment: If in FF the `this` value was the success function itself, then *that* is a mozilla bug.

Comment: @RobG how do I set its `this`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the correct *this* by keeping a closure to the instance, then setting it as *this* in the call:

```
SoundRecorder.prototype.recordSound = function() {

  // Keep reference to this, i.e. instance calling the method
  var soundRecorder = this;

  navigator.getUserMedia = navigator.getUserMedia || navigator.webkitGetUserMedia ||
                           navigator.mozGetUserMedia || navigator.msGetUserMedia;
  if (!navigator.getUserMedia) {
    alert('Media is not supported in your browser');
    return;
  }

  navigator.getUserMedia({audio: true},

                         // Call the functions, setting their this to the instance
                         function() {soundRecorder.success()},
                         function() {soundRecorder.failure()}
  );
};
```

The duplicate answer referenced by Bergi says that.